# Path homotopy from $(f ∗ g) ∗ h$ to $f ∗ (g ∗ h)$.

Tags: general-topology

From page 2 in this link: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~anushakr/Math601/HW1_soln.pdf,

the homotopy between $(f ∗ g) ∗ h$ and $f ∗ (g ∗ h)$ is build as:

$$H(t,s)=f(\frac{4s}{1+t}) \space \text{if}\space  0 \leq s \leq \frac{1+t}{4},$$
$$=g(4s-1-t) \space \text{if}\space  \frac{1+t}{4} \leq s \leq \frac{2+t}{4},$$
$$=h(\frac{4s}{2-t} - \frac{2+t}{2-t}) \space \text{if}\space  \frac{2+t}{4} \leq s \leq 1.$$

My confusion is as to why the path homotopy is split so as to spend $\frac{1+t}{4}$ time "doing f", then $\frac{1}{4}$ time "doing g", then $\frac{2-t}{4}$ doing h". It makes intuitive sense to me that the homotopy should spend "portions" of the time covering the path of each function, but it is unclear to me why the split occurs as above. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $(f*g)*h$ spends $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time doing $f$ and $g$, and $\frac{1}{2}$ of the time doing $h$. Similarly, $f*(g*h)$ spends $\frac{1}{2}$ of the time doing $f$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time doing each of $g$ and $h$.

The split of $\frac{1+t}{4}$ for $f$, $\frac{1}{4}$ for $g$, and $\frac{2-t}{4}$ for $h$ is such that when $t=0$ we get $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}$ (same as for $(f*g)*h)$), and when $t=1$ we get $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}$ (same as for $f*(g*h)$). As $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the proportions linearly interpolate between the proportions for $(f*g)*h$ and the proportions for $f*(g*h)$.

Note that you don't *have* to choose a linear interpolation, but it is the simplest choice.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!